# Ultrasound wave/beam generation

Tags: waves, acoustics

I am coming from a electronics/software background, so please bear with me if this question is somewhat lacking in the standard expected here.

I have been doing some reading into how ultrasound imaging works (for medical/NDT applications) and I am confused on one particular aspect of US generation.

## Single crystal

[Some sources](http://www.sprawls.org/ppmi2/USPRO), indicate that by design of the transducer, an ultrasound "wave" is generated by each "point" on the crystal, the individual waves interfere constructively and destructively to result in a rather narrow "beam" where the intensity is high. Assuming a small (0.2 mm <= w <= 1 mm) 
rectangular crystal, the width of the beam is smaller/same/comparable to that of the crystal (depending on the focusing) 
while the length of the beam is much longer.

[image: beam.png]

## Arrays of crystals

[Other sources](http://www.ultrasonix.com/wikisonix/index.php/Transmitting_Ultrasound_Pulses#Shape_of_the_Ultrasound_Pulse_as_a_Function_of_Space) indicate by using arrays of crystals (e.g., 100s) and appropriate electronic control the beam can be steered. For this approach to work, the diagrams conveniently show the [individual "waves"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array_ultrasonics) (ignoring the "beam" behavior as explained in case 1) that are generated by the crystals which are pulsed at different times such that a "beam" is produced (due to constructive/destructive interference) in the desired direction.

[image: array.png]

Given that in approach 1, the waveform generated is treated as a "beam" why wouldn't it be more like in the below diagram in case 2?
(t1, t2, t3, t4 are different times)

[image: array2.png]